# Error attempting to programatically apply Entity Framework Code First Migrations

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am attempting to use code first migrations for Entity Framework 6.0

This is for a desktop (WPF) app which is currently in use at a couple of sites with their own copy of the database, so running update-database from the package manager console is of no use.

I had been hitherto using automatic migrations, but I now need to apply a more complex migration than this will allow. The new migration does get applied properly if

```
update-database -force
```

option is used (of course, restoring the database to its pre-updated state before testing what follows)

The `DbConfiguration` (which had been working with `AutomaticMigrations`) had been set up like so:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(ContextCeConfiguration))]
public class TrialDataContext : DbContext, ITrialDataContext
{
   ...
}

public class ContextCeConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{

    public ContextCeConfiguration()
    {
        SetProviderServices(
            SqlCeProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName,
            SqlCeProviderServices.Instance);
        SetDatabaseInitializer<TrialDataContext>(new DataContextInitialiser());
    }
}

class DataContextInitialiser : MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TrialDataContext,TrialDataConfiguration>
{
}

internal sealed class TrialDataConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<BlowTrial.Domain.Providers.TrialDataContext>
{
    public TrialDataConfiguration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

I have changed the DbMigrationsConfiguration class to:

```
internal sealed class TrialDataConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<BlowTrial.Domain.Providers.TrialDataContext>
{
    public TrialDataConfiguration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        DbMigrator migrator = new DbMigrator(this);
        if (migrator.GetPendingMigrations().Any())
        {
            migrator.Update();
        }
    }
```

However, the line:

```
DbMigrator migrator = new DbMigrator(this);
```

Is causing the exception:

> ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance.

Can someone please suggest how/where I should instantiate the instance of `DbMigrator` so that updates can be programatically applied

Comment: A stack trace would help.

Comment: Getting the exact same error. The proposed solution does nothing at all to help.